# how to firebase dynamic link whitelist error fix in url pattern?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links

[image]

I am getting an error like the picture above.

my firebase console url pattern

```
^https://my-website/share?category=community&id=.*$
^https://my-website/share?category=.*&id=.*$
^https://.*.com/.*$
```

my dynamic link code

```
Firebase.dynamicLinks.shortLinkAsync {
                                            link = Uri.parse("https://my-wabsite/share?category=community&id=${item.communityId}")
                                            domainUriPrefix = "https://nodeline.page.link"
                                            // Open links with this app on Android
                                            androidParameters("my-package") {
                                                minimumVersion = 220
                                                fallbackUrl = Uri.parse("https://my-website/share?category=community&id=${item.communityId}")
                                                socialMetaTagParameters {
                                                    title = " "
                                                    description = "${item.content}"
                                                    imageUrl = if (item.images.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                                                        Uri.parse("https:/.amazonaws.com/dsfsdf.jpeg")
                                                    } else {
                                                        Uri.parse(item.images[0])
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            iosParameters("my-my-package") {
                                                appStoreId = "1521778128"
                                                minimumVersion = "1.4.8"
                                                setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse("https://my-website/share?category=community&id=${item.communityId}"))
                                                socialMetaTagParameters {
                                                    title = " !"
                                                    description = "${item.content}"
                                                    imageUrl = if (item.images.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                                                        Uri.parse("https:// .amazonaws.com/dsfsdf.jpeg")
                                                    } else {
                                                        Uri.parse(item.images[0])
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            buildShortDynamicLink()
                                        }.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                                            val shortLink = result.shortLink
                                            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

                                            intent.type = "text/plain"
                                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shortLink.toString())

                                            Timber.d("Test Checked asdf \n $shortLink")

                                            (context as Activity).startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Link"))


                                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                                            Log.d("log_tag", "==> ${it.localizedMessage}", it)
                                        }
```

In ios, it is possible to enter the app with the link I created, but in aos, when I click the link I created, a white list error appears like that.

Looking at the error content, it seems that I have set the url pattern incorrectly. Can you tell me what the problem is?

error

```
400: We could not match param 'https://my-website/share?category=community&id=615129' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project.
```

Comment: after create URL pattern, just update your google-service.json file in your project

Comment: i am getting similar error did you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

For my part, I removed some slashes and it worked. Here is the model I am currently using :

```
^https://example.com.*$
```

To match subdomains I use this...

```
^https://.*example.com.*$
```

Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: does not work.....